# slider is not showing when site is Up

Tags: javascript, html, slider

Slider in my project is working perfectly in localhost.But it is not at all working when it was Up.Why??I included owl.carousel.min.js for slider.

```
<section id="main-slider">
    <div class="owl-carousel">
        <div class="item" style="background-image: url(images/slider/bg1.jpg);">
            <div class="slider-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="carousel-content">
                                <h2><span>HEADING</span></h2>
                                <p>Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text.  </p>
                                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#">Read More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--/.item-->
         <div class="item" style="background-image: url(images/slider/bg2.jpg);">
            <div class="slider-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="carousel-content">
                                <h2>Your <span>TEXT</span></h2>
                                <p>Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text.  </p>
                                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#">Read More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--/.item-->
    </div><!--/.owl-carousel-->
</section><!--/#main-slider-->
```

Comment: can you show us your `<script type="text/JavaScript" src=".../.../.../owl.carousel.js"></script>` statement

Comment: I solved the problem.It was a mistake in template.Anyway Thank you..